# RMI: unmarshaling event

Tags: java, rmi

Lets, suppose I have the following class:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {
  //how make this method to be called on server side after unmarshaling?
  private void myMethod(){...}
}
```

And I have a remote object:

```
public class RemoteObject implements SomeRemoteInterface {
  public void doIt(Foo foo){...}
}
```

When I call from RMI client `remoteObject.doIt(foo)` then the instance of foo is marshaled and sent to RMI server where it unmarshaled. Can I get the event of coming my foo to server and call myMethod on server side? For analogy in jpa we have `@PostLoad ,@PostPersist` annotation to mark method to be called by JPA implementation.

Comment: If you can change the server-side `RemoteObject`, then simply add a trigger/method call into ` private void doIt(Foo foo){ serverFooArrivedTrigger(); ...}`

Comment: @JayC667 I want to do it automatically because I need to call it from different RemoteObjects and there can be possibility to forget.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you want the server to call the method, what's wrong with having the server call the method? And why is it private?

Comment: @EJP I want it to be called by RMI framework automatically. Like PostLoad is called by EclipseLink not by my code.

Comment: Well it isn't. You will have to make both methods public and then write the code to have one call the other. Unless you want to write some magic in `Foo.readObject()` or `Foo.readResolve()`, which I don't recommend.

Comment: @EJP By other words there are not any triggers in RMI framework?

Comment: There are no triggers in the RMI framework.